# How to open .ppt, .pptx, .doc, .xlsx files in a webview from the SD card?

Tags: android, webview

"How to open .ppt, .pptx,.doc, .xlsx files in android webview within app?"

"This is requirement to open any documents which i have download in sd card and open witin android webview. In the past I have tried lot of google suggested answer which they are open file outside the app using intent and MIME Type or open online file like webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://myurl.com/mySlide.ppt");"

```
       public class WebContentViewActivity extends BaseActivity {
       @BindView(R.id.webView)
       WebView webView;

       private String docUrl="http://docs.google.com/gview? 
       embedded=true&url=";

       @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new 
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController(this));

         filePath = 
         "/storage/emulated/0/New_Files/1550130536314somefile.pptx";
         fileName = "1550130536314somefile.pptx";

         if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName )){
         Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(fileName );
         webView.loadUrl(fileUri.toString());

         // webView.loadUrl(docUrl+fileUri);//getting 400.That's an error 
         on webview
          }


/**
 * Custom WebView controller class
 */
private class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {
    private Context mContext;
    //TODO : use this flag while open clicked url in the same WebView

    public WebViewController(Context ctx) {
        this.mContext = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        System.out.println("onPageStarted: " + url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Log.v("Webview Error", description);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack())
    {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

I want to show any document file witin webview as above in the code.

Comment: you can't do that using `docs.google.com`, as it has to download the file from the internet, and *obviously* it can't download it from your device.

Comment: Vladyslav above is right. Maybe you could find a 3rd party library to help your task. Luck.

Comment: I agree with your answer it means, i am not unable to view any downloaded docx using webview?